# Adding values to array list with constructor from another class, error message

Tags: java

I'm getting an error saying *cannot find symbol* and it is referring to the bolded area above `cards.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES,i));`.

I have the following constructor in the 'card' class:

```
Card(Suit suit, int rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank; 
}
```

I have declared some enums in that class:

```
public enum Suit {
    SPADES, HEARTS, CLUBS,DIAMONDS 
}
```

The deck class is where the i add to the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList cards = new ArrayList(52);
Deck() {
    //ArrayList cards = new ArrayList(52);
    for (int i=0; i<=13; i++){  
    cards.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES,i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a raw `List`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Suit` is nested inside the `Card` class, so outside of the `Card` class you need to use `Card.Suit.SPADES` or whatever.

Comment: What do you mean it is nested inside Card? You mean the Card calss?

Comment: Yes. For example `public class Card{ public enum Suit { ... } ... }`

Comment: But the card you see above, is a constructor "card" in the card class.

Comment: Right, but the enum itself is defined inside the class. So the type of it is not `Suit` it is `Card.Suit`

Comment: If i were to do this from the main method, would i still need to use Card.Suit? Also this is not needed for other methods i may i have right?

Comment: @user4188409 It is needed anywhere not in the class `Card`.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, seems like `Suit` is an inner enum in `Card`. In code:

```
public class Card {
    public enum Suit {
        //...
    }
}
```

It would be better if you move it into a separate file and then import it in your Deck class properly:

Card.java

```
public class Card {
    //...
}
```

Suit.java

```
public enum Suit {
    //...
}
```

Deck.java

```
public class Deck {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed, that he didn't specify access modifier on constructors? What if both classes are in different packages? :)

Comment: @T.G *It would be better if you move it into a separate file and then **import it in your Deck class properly***

Comment: I would do it this way, also, but his problem is, that he cant access constructor of `Card` in `Deck` because they are probably in different packages. If modifiers to whole classes are also default, then you know where it leads..

Comment: @T.G that's because OP declared `Card` with default scope. OP should declare `public` constructors instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you did not specified access modifiers to your constructors.

If your class Deck is in different package than Card, then you cant access its constructor, because it will have `protected` modifier by default. This means, that constructor cannot be called from outside of a package.

your code

```
Card(Suit suit, int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
protected Card(Suit suit, int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
}
```

however, if you will change your modifiers like below

```
package cards;


public class Card {

    private final Suit suit;
    private final int rank;

    public Card(Suit suit, int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public enum Suit {

        SPADES, HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS
    }
}
```

and

```
package dectks;

import cards.Card;
import cards.Card.Suit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deck {

    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(52);

    Deck() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
            cards.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
    }
}
```

it will start to work.

Conclusion: Dont forget to set access modifiers, dont rely on default values if it is not necessary.

P.S. I also redefined your cars collections to `List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(52);` as it should be done.